# iOS Facebook Connect functionality

Tags: ios, facebook

In the below design we need to connect to facebook from the app itself by entering the username and password in the app textfields. This is similar to the default facebook connect functionality by Apple in iOS6 and iOS7 Settings. So, please suggest how can I approach this design. Thank you guys. :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tJr4.png

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't suggest to use your own views for getting facebook username and passwords for a user. The safest way is to let facebook sdk handle the login flow.

All you need to call is openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: allowLoginUI: completionHandler: after you have successfully integrated the facebook iOS sdk. Publish permissions are always requested in the next step.

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email",nil];

_isUserAuthenticated = [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                                          allowLoginUI:allowUI
                                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                                         NSError *error) {
                                                         if (error) {
                                                             NSLog(@"FACEBOOOK OPEN ACTIVE SESSION ERROR:%@",error);
                                                         //[self handleAuthError:error];
                                                         }
                                                        [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                             state:state
                                                                             error:error];

                                                     }];
```

_isUserAuthenticated is a bool for keeping track of the result.